# How to express the solution points of a matrix in terms of parameters?

Tags: matrices

This is a question which would be helpful to have answered in your response:

"The solution points of the equations

2x+4y = 8

3x+6y = 12

can be expressed in terms of parameter as?"

Comment: say parameter is $t$. put $x=t$, find how much is $y$ in terms of $t$ and thats your answer

Comment: @jack that makes it very simple for me. I feel like an idiot now, but thank you very much.

Comment: Never mind; most of us have gone through this, more or less.